# How to truncate a text depending of the screen resolution

Tags: css

I would like to **truncate a text depending of the screen resolution**.

Currently the code in my tpl file is the following :

```
            {if $category->description}
            <div class="cat_desc">
            {if strlen($category->description) > 190}
                <p id="category_description_short">{$category->description|truncate:190}</p>
                <p id="category_description_full" style="display:none">{$category->description}</p>
                <a href="#" onclick="$('#category_description_short').hide(); $('#category_description_full').show(); $(this).hide(); return false;" class="lnk_more">{l s='More'}</a>
            {else}
                <p>{$category->description}</p>
            {/if}
            </div>
        {/if}
```

Such code allows the display of text truncated to 190 characters whatever the screen resolution is.

I would like to do the following :

- display 300 characters on large screens
- display 100 characters on mobile screens

Would you know how to achieve this goal.

I tried to find css ways such as the one described here :
https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

But using the above method, the text is always limited to one single line. And on large screens, I would like to have the text on several lines.

I thank in advance you for reading and for any help.

Patrick

Comment: Can't this be done using `@media`? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkgmxp1o/)

Comment: Thank you very much @hajile78. I added <p class="ellipsis"> to my tpl file and the recommended code to my css file. Now the full paragraph is displayed on large screens and one single line is displayed on small screens (the full paragraph can be seen when the mouse is over the text)

Answer (score 2):

Im **CSS** you can use such as:

```
// large screen
.textbox { 
    max-width: 600px; 
    word-wrap:break-word; 
}

// override when smaller screen
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .textbox { 
        max-width: 300px; 
        word-wrap:break-word; 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="textbox">Text and text and text</p>
```

To **count characters** a solution in **JS** is needed

Answer (score 1):

I like using the following to accomplish the truncation of text.  I would also use the @media queries that @Michael mentioned.

```css
.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
.ellipsis:hover {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: normal;
  text-overflow: unset;
}
```

```html
<p style='width:150px; border:solid #000 1px;'>Here is some text with out the ellipsis so is not truncated.</p>
<p class='ellipsis' style='width:150px; border:solid #000 1px;'>Here is some text with the ellipsis and it is truncated.</p>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks that's perfect for me, but is there a way to allow showing 2 lines of text?